# Google Sitemaps Puzzle

Tags: php, rss

I'm trying to submit a sitemap for a web site to Google Webtools but I'm getting a very strange error related to the domain name. First of all, I submitted the sitemap as an RSS document which I believe is valid ([Check here](http://vlab.mooo.info/rss/feed/)).

I have two issues. A minor one is that the response carries the header "Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8" but Webtool displays a "Type: ?" message.

[image: Problem - Screenshot]

Second, and most important, is that Web Tool returns an error with the message "
General HTTP error: Domain name not found". However, I am able to resolve the domain name (http://vlab.mooo.info) and the name has been registered months ago, so there shouldn't be a DNS problem.

```
$ resolveip vlab.mooo.info
IP address of vlab.mooo.info is X.Y.Z.W
```

I can't really reach a conclusion: Is there some DNS issue I can't identify? Is there some problem with the syntax of my RSS document? Or something else?

**Update 1:** I did something even simpler! I uploaded a simplistic sitemap.xml file on http://vlab.mooo.info/sitemap.xml. The result is exactly the same. Webtool claims that the domain name cannot be found :S

**Update 2:** Here is yet another error I get from the web crawler:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upload a robots.txt with the following:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

And let the google webmaster tools open it, lets see if it can access that file.
Does your google-analytics account work without any issues?

Normally when adding a new domain to google webmaster tools it cant take up to 48 hours to fully work.

Oh and your feed isn't totally valid.
Remember the w3c services, also for feeds :) http://validator.w3.org/feed/

http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fvlab.mooo.info%2Frss%2Ffeed%2F

Comment: Google Analytics works just fine. I fixed the issues you mentioned and added a robots.txt file. I just noticed that "Crawl Errors" returns also a "Google couldn't access your site because of a DNS error." I tried to "Fetch as google bot" my site and I get a "DNS not found" message.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with your subdomain, has the site been verified correctly? if it hasnt try this To change the verification method, go here:

https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/home?hl=en

Click on Verification Details: and then click on: Verify using a different method.

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/03/dns-verification-ftw.html

Comment: (I updated the question - see update #2) This subdomain was provided by http://freedns.afraid.org/ - it is a free DNS provider but allows you only to have a subdomain, not a whole domain. Do you think this should be a problem?

Comment: It could be the issue yes, but i cant say for sure.

Comment: Yes, this is due to the DNS setup. As per http://freedns.afraid.org/faq/#16 you need to contact the DNS hoster to have them make your subdomain available for Google. This is a somewhat special setup :)